# flask_sqlalchemy query returns ImportError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a Flask web application that has an sqlite database called **data.db** which contains the data of user/admin. Whenever I try to query the data on my python file **routes.py** it returns an ImportError message. However, when I query the data from my conda terminal it works properly, I got the desired result. Is there's any solution for this? I wonder what I did wrong

this is the **init.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'admin_login'

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'my secret key'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///data.db'

from yves_letters import routes
```

this is the **models.py**

```
from yves_letters import db
from flask_login import UserMixin

class Admin(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)
    display_name = db.Column(db.String(20))
    password = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'id: {self.id}, username: {self.username}, display_name: {self.display_name}, password: {self.password}'
```

this is the **routes.py**

```
from yves_letters.models import Data, Admin

@app.route('/')
def home():
    admin = Admin.query.all()
    return render_template('home.html')
```

this is the error I'm getting while running the code

```
ImportError
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\webapp_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 1020, in __call__
Open an interactive python shell in this framereturn self.registry[key]
```

On the other hand, when I do the query from my conda terminal it's working well.

```
admin = Admin.query.all()
admin
```

*[id: 1, username: admin, display_name: Mac Yves]*

Is there's something I missed?

Comment: I assume "Open an interactive python shell in this frame" is a copy-paste artefact?

Comment: The traceback that you added (thank you) contains those words, but htey shouldn't appear in a normal traceback.  But I suspect it's because you are copying from an IDE like PyCharm or VSCode, rather than the terminal?

Comment: @snakecharmerb Yeah that's the error message that appears on my website page. So can you spot exactly where I did wrong?

Comment: @snakecharmerb Another weird thing is that, I've done the exact same thing using the same environment earlier. But this time it doesn't work out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241128/discussion-between-dylan-mac-and-snakecharmerb).